# How to return an object from an api-call-function in Kotlin?

Tags: api, kotlin

I need to make an api-call and deserialize the json response into an instance of a model class (QueryRecipesModel) I wrote. The function should return this instance. I tried using okhttp3 and gson.

```
fun queryRecipes(query: String): QueryRecipesModel {
        lateinit var queryRecipesModel: QueryRecipesModel
        val url="https://api.chefkoch.de/v2/recipes/?query=$query"
        val request = Request.Builder().url(url).build()

        val client = OkHttpClient()
        client.newCall(request).enqueue(object: Callback{

            override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
                val responsecontent = response.body()?.string()
                val gson = GsonBuilder().create()
                queryRecipesModel = gson.fromJson(responsecontent, QueryRecipesModel::class.java)
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
                println("Fail")
            }
        })
    return queryRecipesModel
    }
```

The problem seems to be the enqueue-method in which I initialize my queryRecipesModel, but the queryRecipes function doesn´t recognize it. Using newCall.execute instead doesn´t work either.
Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can't answer the question, because at this moment I have the same. What I can say is queryRecipesModel cannot be returned this way. This function will execute and return before the OnResponse handler has a chance to hydrate the object. In any asynchronous operation, you have to either await the response, return the promise, or execute a callback.